# Feature request: rewards/votes for linked dubplicate question together

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, voting, duplicate-answers

It will be good if people would have ability find same questions, link them and get reputation. It maybe also good to vote for questions are same. That is like vote for link same questions. Another benefit users get doubled answers: some answers from one question and others from second.
This is example:

[Set default syntax to different filetype in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574502/set-default-syntax-to-different-filetype-in-sublime-text-2)

[How to customise file type to syntax associations in Sublime Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088475/how-to-customise-file-type-to-syntax-associations-in-sublime-2)

Questions are same, most voted answers also same, but if we link these questions -- users will have more benefit.

So, I think duplicate questions must be linked together and become one question/merged together. Merge process must be done by comunity by voting and editing.

Man, who link questions, must have ability to be voted by comnunity for this link and gain reputation same as people who as those questions.

Man, who link questions, must have ability to merge both questions (on other words: must ask better. New question must have both questions). The new question must have three editors: first asker, second asker and linker.
Askers must be notified and asked to support new version.

Man, who link questions, must have ability reorder answers from both questions (actually that can be done automatically). Also linker may merge both top answers together, put all author's names into this merged answer, whose answers was used. Those author's must be notified and asked to support new answer.

If question askers support new question the new quesion must be main topic and his question must be closed and marked as duplicated. Asker must continue get reputation for the new question votes as it get for his old.

If asker do not support his question must be subthread of new question. Question become main topic by comunity vouting. For example, question with 1000votes starts to be main topic. When we have main topic subthreads must be closed.

In any case all those question must be linked together and get head like this:

**Merged question Main topic**   views: XXX   votes: XXX

- Question 1 :Duplicate*  view: XXX votes: XXX
- Question 2 :Duplicate (Closed)   views: xxxx   votes: XXX

user see views and votes for questions.

We see that asker2 support new merged question and close his own question and asker2 now coauthor of "Merged question"

asker1 does not suppor "Merged quesion" and his question now subthread of "Merged question"

Viewer now on asker1 subthread. If viewer click "Merged quesion" link head must transform as:

**Merged question Main topic**   views: XXX   votes: XXX

- Question 1 :Duplicate  view: XXX votes: XXX
- Question 2 :Duplicate (Closed)   views: xxxx   votes: XXX

Notice bold.

**Best answers from subthread must be moved to main topic.**

The main idea is that we support all: asker1, asker2, linker by ability the comunity can vote and rise theirs repotation for work/questions they done.

PS. My suggestion is not ideal and I welcome you to edit it.